# HTML5 Video streaming freezes on latest Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I am trying to play a complete video using html5 video tag. Code looks something like below:

```
<video id="playVideo_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" preload="auto" data-setup="{}"
 src="/174-1431369723.mp4">
    <source src="/174-1431369723.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

After couple seconds of rendering, it crashes like this:
(video is still loading, but it is not rendering/playing)
http://imageshack.com/a/img537/614/jNpgCq.png

I am sure the video is not broken, because the same code works completely fine on Safari and Firefox. Anyone has had the same kind of problem?

So currently it crashes at certain points (e.g. right at the 23 second), however if I manually skip that 23 second on video player, it works fine.

(By the way, I am using VideoJS, but I am assuming that is not the issue because I have tried with just pure HTML5 video tag, and it has the same behaviour on chromoe)

Answer (score 1):

Have you experienced something like this with other videos online? It may not be your video or your code.

Since a few weeks ago I've had a couple of computer crashes after viewing pages with html5 video backgrounds. At first the video starts to distort/glitch/pixelate and then the laptop screen goes completely black, the fan turns up, and nothing works. I have to force shutdown.

An examples of a webpage where this happens is the home page of todoist. Also on this page:
http://shopkeeper.getbowtied.com/home/slider-example-full-screen-video/

It happens in chrome and firefox. Both latest versions. I didn't test other browsers.

I have found something that has fixed it for chrome: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube/T6hNpETUu_U/9DJrvuEkeTAJ
The problem described there is different than what I'm experiencing but it worked nonetheless.